# Buffer a cloud task that requires OIDC authentication

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to use the preview buffer [feature](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#buffertask_method) of GCP Cloud Tasks to create an HTTP task on a queue.

There is queue level routing set on the queue which forwards to a cloud run service which is configured with security using IAM.

When I submit a task via the buffer api I must provide a header with an access token however Cloud Run expects an identity token.

Is this a limitation of the buffer method of creating tasks or is there some way to get it to use an identity token when it executes the task?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently struggling with this myself.

So far I am one step further by adding an additional `X-Serverless-Authorization` header to the request which contains an OIDC Token.

You can read more about it in the official docs:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token

So with this additional header you are able to:

- Add the OAuth access token to the `Authorization` header needed to invoke the Cloud Tasks Buffer API endpoint
- Add the Cloud Run specific OIDC Token to the `X-Serverless-Authorization` header